# Locked out of my Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, lets-encrypt

Everytime I try to log in (SSH) to my Ubuntu 14.04 server (DigitalOcean)  it opens Letsencrypts certbot and asks me to choose a domain to install SSL on (already have it activated).
But after that, it automatically closes the connection, without me being able to do anything else.

I've tried:

- FTP | result: `Error: Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server`
- Root login | result: Same thing happens as with my own account
- Adding commands to SSH, `ssh -t user@domain echo hello` | result: `letsencrypt: error: File not found: echo hello`

I have a Magento webshop installed on it and that's it.
A little while back, there was no problem at all and I didn't change anything so I have no idea how this suddenly happened...

Comment: do you have physical access to the server?

Comment: No, it's on DigitalOcean

Comment: It is possible to get access to the server console on DO.

Comment: I've tried that, but does the exact same thing

Answer (score 4):

I would first try to ssh in and disable profile and rc initialisation

```
ssh example.com -t "bash --noprofile"
```

or

```
ssh example.com -t "bash --noprofile --norc"
```

If that didn't work I might try a different shell `sh` or `csh` ...

Failing that try logging in via the out of band console or rescue mode etc if available.

Comment: I've tried the first 2 examples and it responds the following: `ssh user@domain -t "bash --noprofile --norc"
user@domains's password: 
WARNING: unable to check for updates.
Requesting root privileges to run certbot...
  /home/user/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt -c bash --noprofile --norc`